# How to attach to PyCharm debugger when executing python script from bash?

Tags: python, bash, debugging, pycharm, pdb

I know how to set-up run configurations to pass parameters to a specific python script.  There are several entry points, I don't want a run configuration for each one do I?  What I want to do instead is launch a python script from a command line shell script and be able to attach the PyCharm debugger to the python script that is executed and have it stop at break points.  I've tried to use a pre-launch condition of a utility python script that will sleep for 10 seconds so I can attempt to "attach to process" of the python script.  That didn't work.  I tried to import pdb and settrace to see if that would stop it for attaching to the process, but that looks to be command line debugging specific only.  Any clues would be appreciated. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can attach the debugger to a python process launched from terminal:

Use Menu `Tools` --> `Attach to process` then select python process to debug.

If you want to debug a file installed in `site-packages` you may need to open the file from its original location.

You can to pause the program manually from debugger and inspect the suspended Thread to find your source file.